# How should I return a lambda function from a function in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: lambda

Unable to understand how to return a lambda from a method. Anyone’s help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you’re trying to add two integers and will return an integer result.

In Kotlin, we can simply create a normal function like this:

`fun addTwoNumbers(first: Int, second: Int): Int = first + second`

Now let’s create another method which will return a lambda, like the following:

`fun sum(): (Int, Int) -> Int = { x, y -> addTwoNumbers(x, y) }`

As you can see, the return type of sum() is **(Int, Int) -> Int**, which means this is returning a lambda.

And for creating lambdas, we will simply use **{ }** and will write the function body inside these parenthesis, like this: **{ x, y -> addTwoNumbers(x, y) }**

This type of functions are also known as **Higher Order Functions**.

Now, we can simply use it like the following:-

```
fun main() {
    val summation = sum()
    println(summation(100, 300))
}
```

This will print **400** in the console.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! It's now crystal clear to me. Thank you once again.

Comment: Happy coding! :)